# Oracle Procedure to REST API

Tags: oracle, rest, api, stored-procedures, package

Not sure if Devs do this. But What if we want to transform an Oracle PL/SQL procedure into a REST API. What can be the right strategy if you plan to do so?

Note: I am talking about transforming existing packages and procs to REST APIs. No creating new.

Answer (score 2):

At my current job, we use 2 different methods:

1. Use ORDS, Oracle REST Data Services.
2. Build a REST API layer in Java or whatever, which accesses the Oracle database.

Comment: Thanks @theoa. I will check. If there is a best documentation on that you think, please share.

Comment: ORDS looks more like orchestrating the DB as REST. Not transforming the existing Packages/Procs to APIs.

Comment: I have not much experience with ORDS, and I prefer to not use it.
It is probably the way to go in an Oracle-only environment, but I think it has too many drawbacks.
My preferred way is to build a Java/Kotlin service, based on spring boot.

Either way, you will have to write code. There is no magical conversion to RESTful API as far as I know.

Comment: ORDS can be used to expose existing PL/SQL; no problem. See here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-auto-plsql. If you need something more robust, you may have to write some basic wrapper functions around your existing PL/SQL (probably not a bad idea anyway, for security purposes).

Comment: Generally, enterprises implement Oracle OSB, which is an ultimate proposal by Oracle to the Organisation with complex business logic in Stored Procedures. I am in a situation where the OSB is already in place, but still, the business logic is in SPs. I want to take the biz logic out from the SPs and create proper backend APIs.